# Using REST web services add meetings and meetings_contacts relationship using set_relationship method

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm

i have tried to set a relationship between the Meetings created and assigned contacts using rest ,Following is my code .. meetings are inserted successfully but i have no idea why assigned contacts are not saved into a meetings_contacts table

```
$login_parameters = array(
        "user_auth"=>array(
                "user_name"=>'rocks',
                "password"=>md5('rocks'),
                "version"=>"1"
        ),
        "application_name"=>"VanareClient",
        "name_value_list"=>array(),
 );

$data = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);

$set_contact_parameters = array (
                'session' => $data->id,


                'module_name' => 'Meetings',


                'name_value_list' => array( array (
                    "name" => "name",
                    "value" => "Subject" 
            ),
            array (
                    "name" => "description",
                    "value" => "description" 
            ),

            array (
                    "name" => "location",
                    "value" => "Pune" 
            ),

            array (
                    "name" => "duration_hours",
                    "value" =>"1" 
            ),
                ) );
 $dataMeeting = call ( "set_entry", $set_contact_parameters, $url );

 $parameters = array(
                'session' =>  $data->id,
                'module_name' => 'Meetings',
                'module_id' => $dataMeeting->id,
                'link_field_name' => 'meetings_contacts',
                'related_ids ' => array('25627846-a8a2-eeb5-3565-532035113842'),
 );

$dataContactMeetings = call ( "set_relationship", $parameters, $url );
```

this is what i was trying .. please help me how to insert the relationship of meetings and contacts into a meetings_contacts mysql table . I am Using Sugarcrm CE 6.5.16 version .

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
'link_field_name' => 'contacts',
```

since the link field name is 'contacts' ( the relationship name is 'meetings_contacts' ).